# Number Theory, using order of integers

Tags: number-theory

I have $k = 37$ and $m = 101$
How do I find $a$, given the value of $a^k \bmod m$?

I think this has to do with order of integers.

Comment: Is there some more to the question, or are you asking for a general technique for exponentiation under modular arithmetic?

Comment: More of an explanation of how I would be able to recover a.

Comment: So you are given the value of $a^k \bmod m$, and need to find possible value(s) for $a$?

Comment: Yes, given k and m.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can find $n$ such that $nk \equiv 1 \bmod (m-1)$, then $(a^k)^n \equiv a \bmod m$ by [Fermat's Little Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) (since $m$ is prime).

So you need to find the [multiplicative inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse) of $k \bmod (m-1)$.

In this case, $k=37$ and $37^{-1} \bmod 100 = 73$. So $(a^{37})^{73} \equiv a \mod 101$.

---

I'll add an illustration of finding $37^{-1} \bmod 100$ using the [extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm):

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
n & s & t & q \\ \hline
100 & 1 & 0 &  \\
37 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\
26 & 1 & -2 & 1 \\
11 & -1 & 3 & 2 \\
4 & 3 & -8 & 2 \\
3 & -7 & 19 & 1 \\
1 & 10 & \color{red}{-27} & 3 \\
\end{array}$$

On each line, $n=100s+37t$.

On the last line, $1 = 10\times 100 + (-27)\times 37$, so $-27\times 37 \equiv 1 \bmod 100$ and $-27 \equiv \color{red}{73} \bmod 100$. As you can perhaps see, you don't actually need to calculate the $s$ values for this.